# How to trigger re-indexing of the alfresco repository?

Tags: lucene, alfresco, alfresco-share

Whenever I execute a lucene search query on the location property of a people I get a smaller than expected list of people. I notice that however If I create new persons they're included in the list but with the already existing users (repo data restored from backup) changing and updating the location doesn't include then in the set. So I suspect that a re-indexing of the repository is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if you're using the older in-transaction Lucene indexing, or the newer SOLR indexing.

If you're using SOLR, the steps are [given in this part of the Alfresco documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/solr-reindex.html). Basically, stop the Tomcat that hosts SOLR, delete the index directories and the models directories, and start it again. SOLR will then do a clean rebuild of the index. Full steps in [the solr troubleshooting documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/solr-monitor-troubleshoot.html), if you're not sure which directories you need to delete and which to leave!

For the older Lucene indexing, the [documentation is this page](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/adminconsole-searchservice-lucene.html). Basically, you need to set `index.recovery.mode=FULL` in your alfresco-global properties, stop the Alfresco Repository, zap the index directory, and start the repo again.

Comment: Looks like Alfresco decided to change all their documentation URLs recently :( Hopefully pointing to the new locations now